# Can DAX calculate a running P90 across several columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentile

I've got a dataset of rainfall across several years, for each day of the year. I want to calculate the P90 rainfall value across all years. I've calculated the static values myself in Excel but I'm trying to replicate it in PowerBI.

I've tried using Calculate(Percentilex.inc(... but it wants an expression within the percentilex expression, which I don't understand.

A condensed version of my data is below. I effectively need a P90 for each row, which is based on the value for all the years, but as I'm using multiple values, DAX complains

```
  Date    2012   2013   2014   2015  
  01/01    6.1    0.5    7.7    3.9  
  02/01    1.1    1.4    3.0    0.5  
  03/01   16.3    0.7    3.8    2.7
```

Comment: You can read this article about Percentilex in DAX:
https://www.daxpatterns.com/statistical-patterns/

Comment: You can also show your expected output from this input data set.